# Как сохранить изображение средствами PHP после обработки?

Tags: php

Есть такой скрипт, например, вот: [сложное масштабирование изображений в PHP](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/Image-Resize-GD/). Он редактирует изображение прежде, чем отправить его браузеру. В итоге картинка на сервере остается прежней. Есть ли возможность итоговую картинку еще и сохранить на сервер? Чтобы в последующем не использовать скрипт, а выводить сразу ее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Справка по gd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) даёт следующие функции: [imagepng](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)(), [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)(), [imagegif](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php)(), [imagewbmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagewbmp.php)(), - которые позволяют сохранить картинку в файл соответствующего формата.